# define infile - python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have written a code that used manual input files.

I integrated `with open(input) as input_file` so as to call all the needed arguments directly from the `terminal`.

However, I am getting the following "traceback":

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sumVectors.py", line 32, in <module>
    with open(classA_infile, "rb") as opened_infile_A:
NameError: name 'classA_infile' is not defined
```

Here is the code where the `infile` is defined. Any clues as to where I am going wrong?

```
def main(argv):
    try:
        opts, args = getopt.getopt(\
            argv[1:], "hb:a:o:",\
            ["help", "classB=", "classA=", "output="])
    except getopt.GetoptError as err:
        print str(err)
        usage()
        sys.exit(2)

    class_dictA = {}

    with open(classA_infile, "rb") as opened_infile_A:
        for line in opened_infile_A:
            items = line.split()
            print items


        for opt, value in opts:
            if opt in ("-h", "--help"):
                help_msg()
                usage()
                sys.exit()
            elif opt in ("-a", "--classA"):
                classA_infile = value
            else:
                assert False, "unhandled option"

        if len(opts) < 3:
            assert False, "an option is missing"

        program(classA_infile)


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main(sys.argv)
```

I know it is a simple question, but I can't seem to see where I mixed up something.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: You're defining `opened_infile_A` outside of the `main()` loop, so the program's not seeing it..

Comment: How did you decide that the correct location for the `with` statement was where you put it?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams it is the first line of the file after `ClassA = {}`

Comment: @msturdy when I indent, it tells me `unexpected indent`

Comment: I suspect it would... can you update the above with what you have changed?  the `with` should be included within the `main()` statement

Comment: @msturdy check updated question: `traceback` is still the same now.

Comment: well, yes, you're breaking the indentation, which is very important in Python.  indent these lines so that they follow the rest of the method.

Comment: yes, please see updated question and indentation. I no longer receive the error - but the program no longer gives me an output...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem that I was having was absolutely due to indentation, along the lines of what @msturdy mentioned in the comments. However, the other problem was a crucial line of code that I did not include in the original question. That code is the definition of the program function which calls all of the input arguments and then is repeated again, after the definition of the input files.

See the line above `class_dictA = {}`. By not including this line, I was having indentation problems without even realizing that there was a fundamental error in the code.

```
def program(classA_infile): ### I included this line -- which required the rest of the script to be controlled for indentation.
    class_dictA = {}

    with open(classA_infile, "rb") as opened_infile_A:
        for line in opened_infile_A:
            items = line.split()
            print items

 for opt, value in opts:
            if opt in ("-h", "--help"):
                help_msg()
                usage()
                sys.exit()
            elif opt in ("-a", "--classA"):
                classA_infile = value
            else:
                assert False, "unhandled option"

        if len(opts) < 3:
            assert False, "an option is missing"

        program(classA_infile) ## here is where the `arg def` is called.


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main(sys.argv)
```